# Detect kafka events in kiali

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, microservices, istio, kiali

I'm doing a microservice architecture using istio and kubernetes and two microservices are using kafka to communicate with each other. I enabled kiali to vizualise my service mesh but my problem is that I found no way to see the kafka's events represented in kiali.

Does anyone know how I could do that?
(tell me if you need more information)

Comment: Maybe you should rather hookup tracing as shown at the end of this? https://www.confluent.io/blog/importance-of-distributed-tracing-for-apache-kafka-based-applications

Comment: Perhaps this could help: https://github.com/kiali/kiali/issues/976

Answer (score 0):

There was a couple of issues recently fixed in Kiali to have services such as Kafka correctly represented. See https://github.com/kiali/kiali/issues/2197.

In the current version, you shouldn't have any problem to see traffic flowing through Kafka brokers. Don't hesitate to open an issue on Kiali GitHub is it's not the case.